# R: data.table compare sets of rows

Tags: r, set, data.table, projection

I am working in R with data.tables. I have the following data.table encoding a set of points with coordinates A,B,C,D and index encoding a set the point belongs to.

```
library(data.table)

      A B C D set
   1: 0 0 0 0   1
   2: 1 0 1 0   2
   3: 1 1 1 0   2
   4: 0 1 0 0   2
   5: 1 0 1 1   2
   6: 0 1 0 0   3
   7: 1 1 0 0   3
   8: 0 0 1 0   4
   9: 1 0 1 0   4
  10: 0 1 0 1   4
  11: 0 0 0 0   5
  12: 1 0 0 0   5
  13: 1 1 1 0   5
  14: 1 1 1 1   5

dt = setDT(structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), C = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), set = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "set"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I have another table encoding e.g. probability of each set.

```
   set       mass
1:   1 0.27809187
2:   2 0.02614841
3:   3 0.36890459
4:   4 0.28975265
5:   5 0.03710247

wt = setDT(structure(list(set = 1:5, mass = c(0.27809187, 0.02614841, 0.36890459, 
0.28975265, 0.03710247)), .Names = c("set", "mass"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I would like to have a procedure to create a projection to a subspace e.g. C,D. (Note that original points 1,4,6,7,11,12 coincide in this case, sets 1 and 3 are the same in this subspace as well as sets 2 and 5.

```
unique(dt[,c("C","D", "set")])
>   C D set
 1: 0 0   1
 2: 1 0   2
 3: 0 0   2
 4: 1 1   2
 5: 0 0   3
 6: 1 0   4
 7: 0 1   4
 8: 0 0   5
 9: 1 0   5
10: 1 1   5
```

and to identify the same sets, keep just unique ones and sum the corresponding masses. I.e. in this case:

```
>   C D set
 1: 0 0   1
 2: 1 0   2
 3: 0 0   2
 4: 1 1   2
 5: 1 0   4
 6: 0 1   4

   set       mass
1:   1 0.6469965 % set 1 + set 3
2:   2 0.06325088 % set 2 + set 5
3:   4 0.36890459
```

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar in concept to Frank's, we can map the binary values of each set to a decimal with `x * 2 ^ ((length(x) - 1):0)`. Subsetting, also, for "C" and "D", we get:

```
coords = c("C", "D")
d = data.frame(set = dt$set, 
           val = Reduce("+", Map("*", list(dt$C, dt$D), 2 ^ ((length(coords) - 1):0))))
d
```

Then, we can group identical sets following the same idea:

```
tab = table(d$val, d$set) > 0L ## `table(d) > 0` to ignore the duplicates
gr = colSums(tab * (2 ^ ((nrow(tab) - 1):0)))
gr
# 1  2  3  4  5 
# 8 11  8  6 11

## another (pre-edit) alternative with unnecessary overhead
#gr = cutree(hclust(dist(table(d) > 0L)), h = 0)
#gr                        
#1 2 3 4 5 
#1 2 1 3 2
```

and aggregate based on this group:

```
rowsum(wt$mass[match(names(gr), wt$set)], gr, reorder = FALSE)
#         [,1]
#8  0.64699646
#11 0.06325088
#6  0.28975265
```

Comment: instead of `list(dt$C, dt$D)`, maybe you meant `dt[coords]` (to use the `coords` instead of manually typing them again)?

Comment: @Frank : Initially, I meant to mean `dt[, coords]` but I needed "with = FALSE" so I went with `list(dt$C, dt$D)`.  `dt[coords]` is giving a _"When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be..."_ error - perhaps, I don't have the latest version

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the data.frame vs data.table thing; I should've said the with=FALSE way. Btw, the latest CRAN version does allow `dt[, c("C","D")]`, but with=FALSE is still needed for `dt[, coords]`. According to the NEWS, `dt[, ..coords]` is going to work. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat clunky option: make a unique string for each set, and then group on that.

```
coords = c("C", "D")
gDT = setorder(unique(dt[,c(coords, "set"), with=FALSE]))[,
  .(s = paste(do.call(paste, c(.SD, .(sep="_"))), collapse="."))
, by=set, .SDcols = coords][, 
  g := .GRP
, by=s][]

#    set           s g
# 1:   1         0_0 1
# 2:   2 0_0.1_0.1_1 2
# 3:   3         0_0 1
# 4:   5 0_0.1_0.1_1 2
# 5:   4     0_1.1_0 3

gDT[wt, on=.(set), mass := i.mass ]
gDT[, .(set = first(set), mass = sum(mass)), by=g]

#    g set       mass
# 1: 1   1 0.64699646
# 2: 2   2 0.06325088
# 3: 3   4 0.28975265
```

*Comments*

- You can get rid of the `g` by chaining on `[, g := NULL][]` in the last line.
- `setorder` is just sorting the data so that the unique string turns out the same in set sets that are the same.
- Grouped `first` and `sum` operations are optimized, as you can see if you add `verbose = TRUE` to the final line, like `gDT[, .(set = first(set), mass = sum(mass)), by=g, verbose=TRUE]`.